# How can I extract the result of mongoose call and pass it into a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I tried getting it out by making it into a function and passed return, and failed in doing so.

I saw an example where someone used `module.exports.VariableName = objects;`

My issue is I still can't access or use that VariableName. e.g. `var names = Collection;` on the same file.

ReferenceError: Collection is not defined

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

```js
mongoose.connection.on('open', function(ref) {
  console.log('Connected to mongo server.');
  //trying to get collection names
  mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, names) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      module.exports.Collection = names;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: If the `require` to this file runs before the `listCollections` runs, then it wont have `Collection` key

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assigning to `module.exports` a result of an async operation. This means you are most likely assigning this data **after** you are accessing it with `require()`.

By considering only the provided code, one way to solve this would be to wrap your code into a promise that resolves with the `names`:

```
module.exports = function(mongoose) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    mongoose.connection.on('open', function (ref) {
      console.log('Connected to mongo server.');
      //trying to get collection names
      mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, names) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        else {
          resolve(names);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

And then use it like:

```
require('PATH_TO_CODE_ABOVE')(mongoose).then(function(collection) {
  console.log(collection); // This logs the names collection
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err); // this will log an error, if it happens
});
```